# Cannot invoke '==' with an argument list of type '($T2, OSStatus)' in Xcode 6.1

Tags: xcode, swift

When i was on Xcode version 6, the class i was using for accessing the Keychain was working but now in version 6.1 it is not working

Here is a part of the Keychain access class:

```
class func setData(value: NSData, forKey keyName: String) -> Bool {
    var keychainQueryDictionary: NSMutableDictionary = self.setupKeychainQueryDictionaryForKey(keyName)

    keychainQueryDictionary[kSecValueData as String] = value

    // Protect the keychain entry so it's only valid when the device is unlocked
    keychainQueryDictionary[kSecAttrAccessible as String] = kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlocked

    let status: OSStatus = SecItemAdd(keychainQueryDictionary, nil)

    if Int(status) == errSecSuccess { //I GET THE ERROR HERE
        return true
    } else if Int(status) == errSecDuplicateItem {
        return self.updateData(value, forKey: keyName)
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

It is not the only place where it is doing it here is another part of the code:

```
class func removeObjectForKey(keyName: String) -> Bool {
     let keychainQueryDictionary: NSMutableDictionary = self.setupKeychainQueryDictionaryForKey(keyName)

    //Delete
    let status: OSStatus =  SecItemDelete(keychainQueryDictionary);

    if Int(status) == errSecSuccess { //GET ERROR HERE
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

It look likes the problem is with errSecSuccess can somebody help me please

Comment: What is `errSecSuccss`, and why do you cast `status` to an `Int`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`OSStatus` is an alias for `Int32`, so I think you solve that by removing the conversion to `Int`, like in:

```
if status == errSecSuccess {
```

---

Side note: your multiple `if/elseif/else` can be replaced by a `switch`:

```
switch (status) {
case errSecSuccess:
    ...

case errSecDuplicateItem:
    ...

default:
    ...
}
```

more readable in my opinion